# How can we concatenate multiple results filtered through 'where' statement in SQL

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

There are two tables look like:

financials:

```
policy_id   state   coverage    earned_premium_dollar_amount    
1            OH       bi          1.7   
1            OH      umuim        0.82  
2            OH      coll         13.34 
3            TX      coll         13.28
6            TX      comp         6.55
`
`
`
```

territories:

```
state   bi     pd    comp   coll
TX     1.01   1.12   0.82   0.93
TX     1.88   1.39   2.63   1.32
OH     1.87   1.29   2.1    1.02
`
`
`
```

The goal is:

- First, we need to calculate the average of bi, pd, comp and coll which group by 'state' respectively as the territory factors in table territories. Because the territories table only contains 4 coverages, we will assume that coverages that aren't represented in the territories table have a factor of 1.
- Second, create a new column called new_earned_premium_dollar_amount by respective coverage divide by state territory factor. For example, in the financials table, the coverage of the first column is bi and the state is OH, therefore we need to use 1.7 divides by the average number of bi for OH from the territories table.

I wrote a SQL query to find out when the coverage is 'coll' like this:

```
select *,
f.earned_premium_dollar_amount/t.avgcoll as new_earned_premium_dollar_amount
from (select *
from finacials) f
left join
(select state, cast(AVG(bi) as decimal(38,2)) avgbi,cast(AVG(pd) as decimal(38,2)) avgpd,cast(AVG(comp) as decimal(38,2)) avgcomp,cast(AVG(coll) as decimal(38,2)) avgcoll
from territories
group by state) t
on t.state=f.state 
where coverage='coll'
```

and the result is:

```
policy_id   state   coverage earned_premium_dollar_amount state         avgbi   avgpd   avgcomp avgcoll new_earned_premium_dollar_amount
2             OH    coll        13.34                       OH          1.77    1.59    2.32    1.45    9.2
4             OH    coll        18.16                       OH          1.77    1.59    2.32    1.45    12.5241379310345
8             OH    coll        1.13                        OH          1.77    1.59    2.32    1.45    0.779310344827586
12            OH    coll        18.16                       OH          1.77    1.59    2.32    1.45    12.5241379310345
2             TX    coll        13.34                       TX          1.53    1.29    1.97    1.22    10.9344262295082
`
`
`
```

I only got the result of 'coll'. How can I get the rest result and combine them? Similarly, I can get the result of 'pd' by the following code:

```
select *,
f.earned_premium_dollar_amount/t.avgpd as new_earned_premium_dollar_amount
from (select *
from finacials) f
left join
(select state, cast(AVG(bi) as decimal(38,2)) avgbi,cast(AVG(pd) as decimal(38,2)) avgpd,cast(AVG(comp) as decimal(38,2)) avgcomp,cast(AVG(coll) as decimal(38,2)) avgcoll
from territories
group by state) t
on t.state=f.state 
where coverage='pd'
```

The result is:

```
policy_id   state   coverage  earned_premium_dollar_amount      state      avgbi    avgpd   avgcomp avgcoll new_earned_premium_dollar_amount
4            OH       pd           8.91                          OH         1.77    1.59       2.32  1.45   5.60377358490566
11           OH       pd           1.3                           OH         1.77    1.59       2.32  1.45   0.817610062893082
```

Question:

I think I might use join to join those results, but I don't know how can I do it.
Or, is there any different way to achieve my goal?

·················································································

Thanks for Bjeran's answer. This code works:

```
select *,
case 
    WHEN f.coverage = 'bi' THEN f.earned_premium_dollar_amount/t.avgbi
    WHEN f.coverage = 'pd' THEN f.earned_premium_dollar_amount/t.avgpd
    WHEN f.coverage = 'comp' THEN f.earned_premium_dollar_amount/t.avgcomp
    WHEN f.coverage = 'coll' THEN f.earned_premium_dollar_amount/t.avgcoll
    else f.earned_premium_dollar_amount/1
    end as 'new_earned_premium_dollar_amount'
from (select *
from finacials) f
left join
(select state, cast(AVG(bi) as decimal(38,2)) avgbi,cast(AVG(pd) as decimal(38,2)) avgpd,cast(AVG(comp) as decimal(38,2)) avgcomp,cast(AVG(coll) as decimal(38,2)) avgcoll
from territories
group by state) t
on t.state=f.state
```

The final results look like below:
[image]

Now, the only problem is state column appears twice. I might consider using different join rather than left join.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The database only includes two tables, financials and territories, which I showed on the top.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case-statement for the different cases of coverages.
(MySQL Syntax, other should be similar)
Extend this for your other coverages

```
select *,
CASE
    WHEN f.coverage = "bi" THEN f.earned_premium_dollar_amount/t.avgbi
    WHEN f.coverage = "pd" THEN f.earned_premium_dollar_amount/t.avgpd
    WHEN f.coverage = "comp" THEN f.earned_premium_dollar_amount/t.avgcomp
    WHEN f.coverage = "coll" THEN f.earned_premium_dollar_amount/t.avgcol
    ELSE "Coverage unclear"
END AS "new_earned_premium_dollar_amount"
from (select *
from finacials) f
left join
(select state, cast(AVG(bi) as decimal(38,2)) avgbi,cast(AVG(pd) as decimal(38,2)) avgpd,cast(AVG(comp) as decimal(38,2)) avgcomp,cast(AVG(coll) as decimal(38,2)) avgcoll
from territories
group by state) t
on t.state=f.state 
;
```

I don't know your Table, but from the first values perhabs an inner join would also fetch the same results.

Comment: Or are you trying to get a result for each state in a single row? Please give an example in that case how the row should look like :)

Comment: Thanks! It works. Now the only problem is that there are two state columns. Maybe I should use different join rather than left join.

Comment: Then don't use `*` but explicitly define columns you want to show: `select policy_id, f.state, ...`